# Can I ignore &nbsp; when taking the data for a var?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I have a table and script that generates the values for the table cells based on one price that exist on this same page. The problem is that when the prices is `> 1000` then the way that pages is created is that it adds `&nbsp;` in order to separate thousands.

**This is price span example:**

```
<span class="price-amount">1&nbsp;609</span>
```

**This is how I grab the data from in it as a value:**

```
var loose = parseInt(document.getElementById("price-amount").innerHTML);
```

This only work until 999 because there is no `&nbsp;`

Is there a way to ignore this   or make it recognizable as a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieve the `textContent` of the element, then replace all spaces with the empty string. Example for your HTML of `1&nbsp;609`:

```js
var loose = parseInt(document.querySelector(".price-amount").textContent.replace(/\s/g, ''));
console.log(loose);
```

```html
<span class="price-amount">1&nbsp;609</span>
```

Example for an input of less than 1000:

```js
var loose = parseInt(document.querySelector(".price-amount").textContent.replace(/\s/g, ''));
console.log(loose);
```

```html
<span class="price-amount">609</span>
```

Comment: Still there is a space between 1 and 6 so it is not a number in this format.

Comment: I thought you wanted `1609`, because spaces get added as thousands separators? Removing the space allows you to parse it as a number - just run the snippet

Comment: Yes, I want it without any spaces between digits but after I apply your suggested changes the script still does not work. Also when I preview your snippet, I see "1 609" with a space between 1 and 6

Comment: The HTML has `&nbsp;`, so the HTML will be *rendered* with a space (can't change that without changing the HTML), but the *logged `loose`* at the bottom is an integer of 1609.

Comment: but adding your fix it breaks the script and start to not work for cases with prices less than 999. Also it do not work with these for above 1000.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having - both "Run code snippet"s result in numbers being logged for `loose`. The first `loose` is `1609`, the second `loose` is `609`. Why do you say that breaks the script?

Comment: There was issue with interpretation of the website but I add one jQuery line for the specific website needs and works fine. Thank you!